# I have a dangling symlink on /etc/resolv.conf and I have no internet

Tags: symbolic-link

On my secondary machine I have been googling and trying several fixes over the past two months now without success. That this critical file is munged up is almost surely the problem. I don't know what file it it should point to, either.

Confusing was the way various commands dealt with problem. `cat` and `gedit` (load) said there was no file. `ls` and locate said there was. So imagine my surprise when I created a file with `gedit` as root (open terminal type `gksudo gedit`) and tried to save and was told the file existed.

Only `cp` pointed out the dangling symlink problem.

Comment: Should be to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` ... and it should be generated at boot time... what tells you it is "dangling"? Please give details of what you are seeing and when

Comment: From a post I thought my conf file might be messed up. So as root cp /home/resolv.conf  /etc/resolv.conf gave cp: not writing through dangling symlink  '/etc/resolv.conf'

Comment: what's the output of `file /etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: @Zanna it's unreadable due to the dangling symlink.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I think deleting it should have worked...